# Serving a static file with <mvc:resources /> tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

### Problem

I am trying to serve a simple plain text file that contains the letters 'abc' via my Spring application. From doing a bit of research, it looks like using the `<mvc:resources />` tag is my best bet, but I am having trouble with getting it to work.

I have a static file `somefile` in a directory `.somedir` that I want to serve without having to route a request through a controller. `somefile` is the only file in the directory. If a user navigates to the page `somedir/somefile`, I want to serve the file so that 'abc' is visible on the browser.

### What I've tried

I added this line to my base-servlet.xml file:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/.somedir/**" location="/.somedir/" />
```

When I test my app in the browser, I get a `file not found` error which causes my server to timeout.

Any ideas of what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

`location` by default search in classpath and you configuration is equivalent to

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/.somedir/**" location="classpath:/.somedir/" />
```

To serve files from filesystem specify `file://` protocol:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/.somedir/**" location="file:/full/path/to/dir/.somedir/" />
```

See also this article with explanation and examples: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources